# What does "high" add to the meaning of this sentence of Tagore's poem?

Tags: adjectives, poetry

> Do not seat your love upon a precipice
>   because it is high.

What is the meaning of the word *high* in this sentence?

Comment: If this is a poem, shouldn't the meaning be entirely up to the reader?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matt Ellen gives a nice answer to the question of what high means.

I would just like to comment on the interpretation of the whole sentence - in poetry, and especially free verse, the following is possible

> Do not seat your love high upon a precipice - it is dangerous.
>
> Do not seat your love upon a precipice just because it is high - and beautiful to look from above.

(other meanings of high can also apply - high in a sense of above, more worthy of others; putting something high and thinking highly of someone)

So, in the poem and especially a seemingly simple like the one quoted, you are often given the opportunity to contemplate not on a single possible interpretation, but on all of them and it can deliberately be written "ambiguously". Actually this kind of "ambiguity", in my eye, carries certain aesthetics, *if* all meanings convey different facets of the same idea or different, but consistent ideas.

Comment: Poetry, by its very nature, is open to different interpretations. I'm sorry to say that I tend to disagree with your analysis.

Comment: Don't be sorry if you are adding to the richness of it. I will quote Borges here, because I am tired: "If the pages of this book contain some successful verse, the reader must excuse me the discourtesy of having usurped it first. Our nothingness differs little; it is a trivial and chance circumstance that you should be the reader of these exercises and I their author."

Answer (score 4):

The precipice is high, as in the same way a mountain is high.

So you should not put you love on the high precipice because that is dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with the poem, but this line could have a variety of meanings.

> Because it is high

can be meant to make us visualize a risky, high precipice, or it can be meant to make us think of how something can be important, or both. For example:

- Do not put your love (the person you love, or your goal or dream) "on a pedestal". To place something or someone on a pedestal is to see no wrong in it, or to elevate it above all else. Perhaps Tagore means "don't put your love above you just because you can" - just because the precipice is high doesn't mean you have to constantly look up to it.
- Do not put your love (your goal or dream) too high, out of reach.
- Do not put your love (a person) in a dangerous place - perhaps meaning to look out for those you love.

Comment: I like this better than my answer.

Comment: +1 similar to mine, but you were faster. let me add, i think your analysis is good, but it should be looked in whole: 1) do not put on high pedestal *if dangerous*, 2) do not put too high *if dangerous*, 3) do not put in *danger* even to be in a beautiful place with nice view

Comment: @unreason I agree those are all possible meanings! One more that you made me think of is jealousy or pride - it doesn't seem to be part of Tagore's poem from what I gather, but if it were, imagine placing your love on the precipice like a trophy... while you're showing off, she or he has a new view; you may lose your love. Ahh, poetry is so complicated ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Don't put your heart in an impossible
>   dream.

***High*** means something too difficult or impossible. This sentence is suggesting to not dream too high and put all your thinking and mind on this dream.

Comment: No. To me the collocation of "high" with "precipice" refers to the risk, not the effort.

Comment: Hm, no - high does not mean impossible nor too difficult, especially after precipice.

Comment: Yeah! I'm wrong on this!

Answer (score 0):

While it is true (as the other answers point out) that `high` may refer to the height or location of the precipice, and also to its status (`high` can mean royal or special, not common), `high` can also refer to intoxication due to a drug or other substance. It is common to associate love with intoxication.